# Отрисовка прямоугольной области при помощи одной функции

Tags: c

Совсем запутался, подскажите алгоритм для отрисовки прямоугольной области (закрашенной и не закрашенной), используя только функцию отрисовки пикселя (принимает x, y, color).

Answer (score 3):

Закрашенный:

```
for( y = cy ; y-- ; ){
  for( x = cx ; x-- ; ){
    putpixel( ox + x, oy + y, color );
  }
}
```

Незакрашенный:

```
for( y = cy ; y-- ; ){
  putpixel( ox, oy + y, color );
  putpixel( ox + cx, oy + y, color );
}
for( x = cx ; x-- ; ){
  putpixel( ox + x, oy, color );
  putpixel( ox + x, oy + cy, color );
}
```

Дополнительные параметры:

ox, oy - смещение прямоугольника
  сx, сy - размеры прямоугольника
 --
Не понимаю, где тут можно запутаться.

Comment: @mega, спасибо! Вынесите это в ответ, чтобы закрыть данный вопрос.

Comment: подправил (ox -> ox + x)